# How to customize ListFieldCallBack?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

i have written a class which implements ListFieldCallBack like,

```
import java.util.Vector;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;


    class ListCallBack implements ListFieldCallback
    {
        private Vector listelements = new Vector();

        public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) 
        {
            String text = (String)listelements.elementAt(index);
            graphics.drawText(text,0,y,0,width);
        }

        public Object get(ListField listField, int index) 
        {
            return listelements.elementAt(index);
        }

        public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) 
        {
            return listelements.indexOf(prefix, start);
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) 
        {
            return Graphics.getScreenWidth();
        }

        public void insert(String toInsert, int index)
        {
            listelements.addElement(toInsert);
        }   
        public void erase()
        {
            listelements.removeAllElements();
        }   
    }
```

And in my constructor having the main class is coded as

```
helloWorld()
{
    mylist = new ListField();
    ListCallBack myCallBack = new ListCallBack();
    mylist.setCallback(myCallBack);
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)//array is a string array
    {
        list_category.insert(i);
        myCallBack.insert(array[i], i);
    }
    this.add(list_category);
}
```

this works properly..

like, i am getting output like,

```
Aby
Eric
Allay
vine
```

But i want to add another string to the next of that array in the each row displayed in list.. How could i do this?

Like, for example, i want my screen output like,

```
Aby     :  Smart
Eric    :  0000
Allay   :  9789
vine    :  Like
```

how could i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `ListFieldCallback.drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width)` to draw that.

Use `net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics` API to draw whatever you want.

Comment: i am really new to blackberry environment. actually i just want to study what functioning is happening there to get my desired result. can u plz show what call changes i need to make in my code?

Comment: @arhimed- dear, i had gone through the way you shown. thank you for your valuable suggestion. i have some doubts. can u help me with my doubts. u may feel all my doubts to be foolishness. but to have someone who can guide me will be more helpful for me. plz reply if u can help me

Comment: @sujith: Please post any of your doubts as new StackOverflow questions and the whole StackOverflow BB community will be abailiable for you to help. Also here is a sample of a bit more coplicated list item drawing for you to check: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ListField-row-with-images-and-text/td-p/227993